# Why i have error result by use IList().toList().AddRange()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, addrange

Those are my old Code that cannot response correct result.

```
IList<string> testList=new List<string>();
testList.Add("string1");
var testList2=new List<string>(testList);
testList.ToList().AddRange(testList2);
```

I expect there are two elements in testList,but in fact it only have one;
If i change my to code to new style ,its can get the right result.Example :

```
IList<string> testList=new List<string>();
testList.Add("string1");
var testList2=new List<string>(testList);
var result=testList.ToList();
result.AddRange(testList2);
```

In result,it successfully have two elements.I guess the reason is iList().toList() create a new List in other place,as param result,that is independent from iList(). Is it right? or other reasons?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know why my old code cannot get the right result.

Comment: Why? The new works, go with that.

Comment: i want to know why ,not just go with the right new

Comment: Yes to list creates new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the extension methods that come with `System.Linq` namespace create a new copy of the object (deep copy, if you will). 
So, you are right when you say that a new list is created at another memory location.

To confirm whether two objects are different, you can get their memory addresses via unsafe and see for yourself. Here is something to test (be cautious if you are using unsafe code; you need to handle all the memory management yourself):

```
unsafe
            {
                IList<string> testList = new List<string>();
                testList.Add("string1");
                var testList2 = new List<string>(testList);
                testList.ToList().AddRange(testList2);

                TypedReference original = __makeref(testList);
                IntPtr originalPointer = **(IntPtr**)(&original);

                var isThisANewList = testList;

                TypedReference newReferenceOnly = __makeref(testList);
                IntPtr newReferenceOnlyPointer = **(IntPtr**)(&newReferenceOnly);

                var copy = testList.ToList();

                TypedReference deepCopy = __makeref(copy);
                IntPtr deepCopyPointer = **(IntPtr**)(&deepCopy);
            }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer and agree with my comment.Thanks again.

Comment: @Moises.Li Updated the response with additional information. Might help.

Answer (score 1):

`ToList()` is an extension method that returns a list. You aren't holding that value in a variable, so although you call `AddRange()`, you are adding to the list you created in `ToList()` not to your testList.

In your second example, you are correctly holding the value of `ToList()` in result.

```
var result=testList.ToList();
result.AddRange(testList2);
```

You have a couple of options...

```
// option 1 declare testList as a List not IList
List<string> testList = new List<string>();
testList.AddRange(testList2);

// option 2 cast testList as a List
((List<string>)testList).AddRange(testList2);
```

Comment: Using IList  in my code is neccssary.Thanks for your answer.